# Partitioning a string and splitting it every n characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I have this `data="6060526060....cont"`. I'd like to split this string into every 4 chars. But if the number `52` appears, i'd like to spit this for `2 chars`. i.e `['6060', '52', '6060']`.

I currently have :

```
r = [data[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(data),4)]
```

this puts it into every 4 chars, just having trouble getting the "52" into 2 seprerate chars, thanks

Comment: What if the string is '605260'?

Comment: Can there be more than one "52"?

Comment: yes, there can be more than one "52" in the string & the string will always start with "6060"

Comment: Is your string always 10 characters long? If so, `list[data.partition('52')]` is what you're looking for.

Comment: the string wont always be 10 chars long no

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is my solution

```
data="606052606080801010521010"

i=0
L = []
while i<len(data):
    if data[i:i+2] == '52':
        L.append(data[i:i+2])
        i+=2
    else:
        L.append(data[i:i+4])
        i+=4
print(L)
```

output

```
['6060', '52', '6060', '8080', '1010', '52', '1010']
```

Answer (score 4):

You might look at splitting over a regex:

```
import re
digits = '6060526060521233'
r = [s for s in re.split('(52|\d{4})', digits) if s]
```

This creates a new split every time `'52'` or a group of four digits is observed. Output:

```
['6060', '52', '6060', '52', '1233']
```

[demo](https://repl.it/repls/HuskyYearlyCables)

Comment: OP didn't specify digits explicitly, so I would add that you could modify the pattern to `'(52|.{4})'` if you wanted to split on any group of 4 characters.

Comment: You can use slicing to remove the unwanted empty groups. Also making the repeat `{1,4}` will pick up any trailing short group at the end. `re.split('(52|.{1,4})', digits)[1::2]`

Answer (score 2):

something I believe is more Pythonist than the previous answer:

```
def iter_data(data, pos=0):
    while pos < len(data):
        if data[pos:pos+2] == "52":
            yield "52"
            pos += 2
        else:
            yield data[pos:pos+4]
            pos += 4

print(list(iter_data(data)))
```

output:

```
['6060', 52, '6060', '8080', '1010', 52, '1010']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using `str.partition` in a `while` loop:

Make the string into a tuple, and repeatedly call partition on the last element. Appending the rest to the original tuple:

```
data="60605260605211110000"
new_data = (data,)
while '52' in new_data[-1]:
    new_data = new_data[:-1] + new_data[-1].partition('52')
print(new_data)
#('6060', '52', '6060', '52', '11110000')
```

If your data is guaranteed to be separated by `'52'` every 4 characters, then you're done here (just convert the output to a list). If not (as I've shown in my example), you need to go through this output and split the longer than 4 char strings:

```
parts = []
for p in new_data:
    if p == '52' or len(p) <=4:
        parts.append(p)
    else:
        parts.extend([p[i:i+4] for i in range(len(p)//4)])
print(parts)
#['6060', '52', '6060', '52', '1111', '1110']
```